# How do you provide an error when an invalid input is provided ie. (a color other than purple or sky blue) or a number

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        color1 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window be, Purple or Sky Blue? > ")).lower().strip()
        color2 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window, white Yellow or Pink? > ")).lower().strip()
        user_info = {"color2": color1, "color2": color2,}
    except ValueError:
        print("Choose a valid input please...")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Trying to get it to give an error and restart the loop but its not working.

Comment: In the actual state, any string will be accepted, so a ValueError will never be raised! Instead test whether color1 and color2 are in some list of legal colors, and break the loop if they are. `if color1 in ['purple', ...] and color2 in [...] : break`

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
while True:
    try:
        color1 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window be, Purple or Sky Blue? > ")).lower().strip()
        color2 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window, white Yellow or Pink? > ")).lower().strip()
        user_info = {"color2": color1, "color2": color2,}
        valid_input1 = ['purple', 'sky blue']
        valid_input2 = ['white', 'yellow', 'pink']
        if color1 not in valid_input1 or color2 not in valid_input2:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Choose a valid input please...")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

You could also do something like this:

```
color1 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window be, Purple or Sky Blue? > ")).lower().strip()
color2 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window, white Yellow or Pink? > ")).lower().strip()
user_info = {"color2": color1, "color2": color2,}

valid_input1 = ['purple', 'sky blue']
valid_input2 = ['white', 'yellow', 'pink']

while color1 not in valid_input1 or color2 not in valid_input2:
    print("Choose a valid input please...")
    color1 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window be, Purple or Sky Blue? > ")).lower().strip()
    color2 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window, white Yellow or Pink? > ")).lower().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't raising `ValueError`, you can change your code to check for invalid input using an `if` statement for each `input`:

```
while True:
    color1 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window be, Purple or Sky Blue? > ")).lower().strip()
    color2 = str(input("What should the color of the broken window, white Yellow or Pink? > ")).lower().strip()
    user_info = {"color2": color1, "color2": color2,}
    if color1 not in ["purple", "sky blue"] or color2 not in ["yellow", "pink"]:
        print("Choose a valid input please...")
        continue
    break
```

Also if you are using Python 3, then `input` returns a string, so passing it to `str` isn't needed.